# How Skia uses OpenGL backend?

Tags: opengl, shader, glsl, 2d-graphics, triangulation

Skia 2D's one notable backend in OpenGL, but how does it work under the hood to render?

Say, we need to draw an anti-aliased circle. Does Skia:

- make a quad (using 2 triangles) and paint the circle on top of it
  using auto generated shaders?
- Or, makes hundreds of triangles and arrange them into a fan? (plus
  possible tessellation)
- Or, something else?

Comment: That's probably something only the people who have the source code can tell you.

Comment: @user1118321 We are all those people. https://github.com/google/skia

Comment: Then why is this even a question? OP can simply go look. Perhaps you could post that as an answer?